# LOCALHOST Display

Tags: linux, rhel

I need to export my display on two oracle database RAC nodes as this
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
However for me localhost:10.0 works on node 1 but on node 2 i have to export display as
DISPLAY=localhost:11.0
Is there a way i could export a display on both hosts as localhost:10.0 ?

Thanks.

Comment: You say " i have to export display as DISPLAY=localhost:11.0" . Why? Do you receive an error message? If so, what message is that?

Comment: @schaiba:  That obviously means that it doesn't work, considering `:11.0` does.

Comment: That is quite unusual unless you keep stopping and restarting X.

Answer (score 4):

When you connect to a remote by `ssh -X` this automatically sets up a reverse channel, over the same connection, to your originating display. It  uses the first free port starting from 6010 and initialises DISPLAY to this minus 6000. If you are getting `localhost:11.0` then probably someone else has already connected and taken that port, so you get the next one.  You would have to kill them and reconnect to get 10.

You should not need to set the DISPLAY explicitly, as you should inherit it in the ssh environment on the remote.

Comment: I rebooted the server and it solved the problem. Ok so let me put it this way, how can i ensure i set the display to be consistent across both nodes - i dont mind putting a random number like localhost=50.0

Comment: @Super It is a bit unusual to want to do this, so I dont know of any simple way. There is an option `X11DisplayOffset` that you can set in the sshd server on the remote, but it would apply to all incoming connections, so you might get 51 instead of 50 if you are the 2nd connection. You could run a 2nd sshd server with this on a different port than 22 just for you.  Or you can setup a `socat` or iptables forward rule from port 6050 to port 6010 (or whatever you got). Or simply allow your local X11 server to accept remote connections and use `DISPLAY=x11server:0`.

Comment: @Super No, you can't guarantee the display number. That's why it's always provided to you through the `DISPLAY` environment variable. (You could set up a TCP forwarding from a port of your choice, but it's a lot of work for something that should not be necessary.)